# jquery equal height needs to work with browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 `h2` headings that I use jQuery to detect the largest heading and then make the other `h2`'s the same height.

However the issue I'm having is that I'm trying to get the height to resize as you drag the browser in an out. Currently you have to change the width of the browser and then refresh the page for the new height to be determined.

I'm pretty sure I need to use [`resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) but I'm struggling to get it to work correctly.

Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var elementHeights = $('.js-eq-height').map(function() {
  return $(this).height();
}).get();
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);
$('.js-eq-height').height(maxHeight);

});
```

```css
.item {
  background:red;
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h2 class="js-eq-height">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In commodo laoreet ipsum in ultricies. Vestibulum neque velit, dictum vitae ornare a, imperdiet in nibh.
    </h2>
    <p>
    Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="js-eq-height">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con
    </h2>
    <p>
    Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item ">
    <h2 class="js-eq-height">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In commodo laoreet.
    </h2>
    <p>
    Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="js-eq-height">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </h2>
    <p>
    Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can make the use of [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: The height of the items are dynamic so I can't use any fixed heights in CSS

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/twdq0boz/

Comment: What about changing the design from horizontal to vertical for small width size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the resize event  set height as auto and calculate the greatest height of the elements and set that height to all the elements with class `.js-eq-height`.

A sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var resizeTimer;

  $(window).on('resize', function(e) {

    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() { 
    
        $('.js-eq-height').height('auto');
        var elementHeights = $('.js-eq-height').map(function() {
          return $(this).height();
        }).get();

        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);
        $('.js-eq-height').height(maxHeight); 

    }, 250);

  }).trigger('resize'); 
});
```

```css
.item { 
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h2 class="js-eq-height">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In commodo laoreet ipsum in ultricies. Vestibulum neque velit, dictum vitae ornare a, imperdiet in nibh.
  </h2>
  <p>
  Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h2 class="js-eq-height">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con
  </h2>
  <p>
  Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="item ">
  <h2 class="js-eq-height">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In commodo laoreet.
  </h2>
  <p>
  Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h2 class="js-eq-height">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </h2>
  <p>
  Aliquam pretium ipsum et enim efficitur venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique erat a massa blandit, vitae iaculis est lacinia. Phasellus vitae convallis ex, eu cursus augue. Aenean rutrum pharetra ex. Praesent id massa urna. Mauris sollicitudin libero eget luctus molestie. 
  </p>
</div>
```